# How to move a particular element in top using orderBy in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of names

```
var arr = [
              {firstName : 'King'},
              {firstName :'Auk'},
              {firstName :'Kish'},
              {firstName :'You'},
              {firstName :'Blob'}
          ];
```

I am using the `orderBy` of angular js on the `firstName` field, like so

```
 <div ng-repeat="name in arr| orderBy: 'firstName'">  
     <p>{{arr.firstName}}</p>// Auk, Blob, King,Kish,You
 </div>
```

But, I want the 'You' in the first place , is there any mechanism to bring that element to top.

Comment: Do you want the order reversed? Or just `You` in front and then the rest as it is?

Comment: @JeremyW Just want 'You' in front

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will can write one more simple filtering function that would handle this special behaviour:

```
<div ng-repeat="name in arr | orderBy:[youSort, 'firstName']">  
    <p>{{name.firstName}}</p>
</div>
```

where function `youSort` would be defined as:

```
$scope.youSort = function(obj) {
    return obj.firstName === 'You' ? '' : name;
};
```

Here is a demo:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr = [
      {firstName : 'King'},
      {firstName :'Auk'},
      {firstName :'Kish'},
      {firstName :'You'},
      {firstName :'Blob'}
  ];
  $scope.youSort = function(obj) {
      return obj.firstName === 'You' ? '' : name;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-repeat="name in arr | orderBy:[youSort, 'firstName']">
        <p>{{name.firstName}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't alter sort order to make this exception. Instead, move the special case outside the repetition.

- Manually include `You` in your template before the `ngRepeat`
- Use `filter` (or off-template processing) to remove `You` from the array
- Pass the other elements through `orderBy`

If the amount of markup is large, and you don't want to write it all twice for `You` and `ngRepeat`, you can create and include a sub-template.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply some custom order to your data, you should order it in your controller.

```
var elem = $scope.arr.pop()
$scope.arr.unshift(elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason want to keep your own record in the repeater, add another property called `sortPrio` or similar. Then sort by `firstName` and `sortPrio`.